# Passing params to function in global, INTERSYSTEM CACHE

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems-iris

I have a problem. I can't find a way to pass parameters to the function, inside teh Global:

set ^SERIES(1)="Nombre de Serie#Humor#10#Do ResultadoSerie^KDAobjetos(respuesta)"
.....
CargaMenu1 ;
New Sql,Statement,status,resultSet,resultado,mensaje

```
Set Sql="select * from SQLUser.Series"

Set Statement=##class(%SQL.Statement).%New()
Set status=Statement.%Prepare(Sql)
If status=1
{       
    Set resultSet=Statement.%Execute()
    While resultSet.%Next()
    {
        Use 0 Write $J(resultSet.IdSeries,5)_".- "_resultSet.NombreSerie,!
    }
}
else 
{
    // No se ha podido ejecutar la consulta.
    set resultado=-1
    set mensaje=$$STATUSERROR^SPAHH000(status)
    Use 0 Write resultado_" : "_mensaje,!
}

// Condicion de salida
Use 0 Write !,$J(0,5)_".- Salir",!
W !,""

Quit
```

CargaMenu2(respuesta)
New objSerie,status
set objSerie = ##class(User.Series).%OpenId(respuesta,,.status)
If status = 1
{

```
    Xecute objSerie.XecuteCode(respuesta)

 }
else
{
    W !,""
    Use 0 write "Opción no disponible.",!   
    hang 2
}
Quit
```

ResultadoSerie(respuesta) ;
set objSerie = ##class(User.Series).%OpenId(respuesta,,.status)
W #,"La serie "*objSerie.NombreSerie*", es de "*objSerie.CategoriaSerie*" y tiene "*objSerie.TemporadasSerie*" temporadas."
W !!, ""
hang 2

```
    Quit
```

Terminal Result :

```
<OBJECT DISPATCH>Function2+9^CargaMenu2 *Property 'XecuteCode' in class 'User.Serie' is not MultiDimensional
USER 3d1>
```

Comment: Please add more details, on what are you trying to achieve. At the moment it's not clear.

Comment: I added more details, ty

Answer (score 1):

Even after update, still does not explain why you need it this way. It's not very good to execute this way some code stored somewhere in the database. I would recommend finding another way.

Anyway, you have to construct the correct string, with all the parameters inside, and execute it. And loot to [the documentation](https://docs.intersystems.com/irislatest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_cxecute). Maybe you'll find a better answer.

Comment: What I am trying to do is pass a parameter (response) to the routine that is inside the database. I am in the process of learning CACHE, and this curiosity has arisen.